# Equate mysqli_num_rows to 0 but it do not work

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query that I get data from mysql table. How can I properly check if there is result returned? My mysql table have 5 rows with data.

**I have tried to equate `mysqli_num_rows` to 0 but it does not work. It always return fail. I need it to return success.**

I can't figure this out, how can I fix this?

my code:

```
$result=mysqli_num_rows($query)

if($result==0)
{
    echo "Success";
}else
{
    echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: This is my code - 

    if(result==0)
    {
        echo "Success";
    }else
    {
        echo "fail";
    }

Comment: My problem is that it always show fail not success.

Comment: Your missing a $ in `if(result==0)` - `if($result==0)`

Comment: yes 5 rows in the table

Comment: you have not added $ sign there with variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement only evaluates to `true` if `mysqli_num_rows` is equal to `1`:

```
if($test = mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
```

You should check if it is equal more than 0, so that it will evaluate true when it returns more than 1 row:

```
$result = mysqli_num_rows($query)

if ($result == 0) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

---

Usage of [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php):

> Returns the number of rows in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

you have an issue with this line

```
result==0 //also no $ sign here

 //try like this

if ($result){

}
```

hope so it will help

```
 <?php
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // data is available 

    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();

    ?>
```

for more please read this
[php_mysql_data](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_mysql_select.asp)

OR

```
  $q='query here';
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$q);
    if (!$result)
        echo(mysqli_error($con));

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    //result here
    }
```